# Haskell fmap over custom data type

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, functor

In my project I have a few data types that look like this

```
data StructureA = StructureA [Int] Bool Int
data StructureB = StructureB [String] String
```

My goal is to map functions over arrays contained inside instances of such datatypes

```
inst = StructureA [1,1,1] True 0
fmap (+1) inst -- [2,2,2]
```

My initial solution solution looks like this

```
instance Functor StructureA where
    fmap (StructureA arr _ _) = fmap arr
```

However, I get kind mismatch error.

Question is how I can declare a function that can be polymorphically applied over such data structures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only declare a `Functor` instance over a *parameterized type* (`* -> *` to be precise): a type that still needs an extra (and exactly one) type parameter.

So first we will need to introduce a type parameter. Even if you never plan to use something else than `Int`s, we can easily abstract that away with:

```
data Structure a = Structure [a] Bool Int
```

We can for example declare the `StructureA` as a *type synomym*:

```
type StructureA = Structure Int
```

Now we can make it a `Functor` instance, by writing:

```
instance Functor Structure where
    fmap f (Structure as b c) = ...
```

Note that we here did *not* write `(Structure a)`, but `Structure`, since - like we already said - `fmap` has the freedom to change the type over which the collection works: the `f` function can have for example type `Int -> Char` to convert a `Structure Int` to a `Structure Char`.

Now we still need to implement `fmap`. `fmap` has type [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) so that means it takes a function, and in this case a `Structure a`, and constructs a `Structure b`. Based on your question (and the design decisions we have made), the only part we can map is the first parameter, so we construct a new `Structure`, where the second parameter is the result of an `fmap f`, but then over the second parameter, so:

```
instance Functor Structure where
    fmap f (Structure as b c) = Structure (fmap f as) b c
```

Comment: That is really helpful, but minor change blows it up (infinite type error):            `instance Functor Structure where
 fmap f (Structure as b c) = Structure (f as) b c` How I can fix that ?

Comment: That minor change is fixed by using the code @willemvanonsem wrote. you try to apply a function that takes a list element to the whole list.

Comment: @user8856277: if you want to call the `f` on the second argument, then you should redefine your `data` type as `data Structure a = Structure a Bool Int`. It gives you in that case more freedom to decide what the second parameter should be.

Comment: Picking a nit: a type constructor of kind `* -> *` is not a higher kinded type, it's just a parameterised type. `Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint` is a higher-kinded type because it has arrows on the left. (I know that you understand this already but a reader may not.)

Answer (score 2):

A type constructor can only be a functor if it has exactly one parameter. The type constructor `StructureA` has no type parameter at all and can thus not be a functor.